# exporting data from one table to another in different database using DOS command

Tags: postgresql

I have to transfer data from old database to new database where table name  and column name is different.
 Can it be done with DOS command or any other solution?
 One is POSTGRESQL and old is MYSQL.

My concern is table name and column names are different, column number is same.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the postgresql part but for sql server you can use `sqlcmd.exe` to export data as text format with or w/o column names

Please check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx